# Bootstrap + JS Validation - ErrorText and Red border not showing up on fields and on Submit

Tags: html, css, validation, twitter-bootstrap-3, jsvalidation

I have written the js validation code without any known issues, but for some reason it's not working on my site or on my fiddle.

How can I change the order of the links or code to make the JS validation work in bootstrap?

https://jsfiddle.net/Lts7rwya/3/

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.validator.addMethod("lettersonly", function(value, element) {
    return this.optional(element) || /^[a-z\s]*$/i.test(value);
  }, "Please enter only letters");
  $.validator.addMethod("numbersonly", function(value, element) {
    return this.optional(element) || /^[0-9\s]*$/i.test(value);
  }, "Please enter only numbers");
  $(".form-contact").validate({
    errorClass: "error-class",
    validClass: "valid-class",
    rules: {
      fullname: {
        required: true,
        lettersonly: true,
        minlength: 5
      },
      youremail: {
        required: true,
        email: true
      },
      phone: {
        required: true,
        maxlength: 13,
        numbersonly: true
      },
      yourmessage: {
        required: true,
        minlength: 10,
        maxlength: 3000
      }
    },
    messages: {
      youremail: {
        required: "Please enter your full email address."
      },
      fullname: {
        required: "Please enter your first and last name.",
        minlength: "Your full name must be at least 4 letters."
      },
      phone: {
        required: "Please enter your full phone number",
        minlength: "Your phone number is too short.",
        maxlength: "Your phone number is too long."
      },
      yourmessage: {
        required: "Don't forget to enter your message.",
        minlength: "Please, add more detail to your message.",
        maxlength: "Please keep the message under 3,000 words/characters."
      }
    },
    highlight: function(element, errorClass) {
      $(element).removeClass(errorClass);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/validate.js/0.10.0/validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.15.0/additional-methods.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div id="message" class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 bordercon">
  <form name="sentMessage" id="contactForm" class="form-contact" action="message.php#contact" method="post">
    <h2 style="margin-top:0px;"><i class="fa fa-1x fa-envelope"></i> Message Us</h2>
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control emailaddress" name="fullname" placeholder="Your Full Name *" id="fullname">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="email" class="form-control emailaddress" name="youremail" placeholder="Your Email Address *" id="youremail">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="tel" class="form-control emailaddress" name="phone" placeholder="Your Phone Number *" id="phone">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <textarea type="text" class="form-control" name="yourmessage" placeholder="Your message, question, or quote request *" id="yourmessage"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
      <div class="buttonwrapper">
        <input class="sendmessage" title="Send Message" type="submit" name="send" value="Send Message">
      </div>
    </div>
    <br />
  </form>
</div>
<script>
  window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"><\/script>')
</script>
```

Comment: That's a large wall of code.  Can you reduce it?

Comment: Ok, I edited, I just left the necessary html and js

Comment: That's still a very large wall.  Also poorly formatted.

Comment: I removed some of the links from the html, I can't format it further. Unless your talking about just displaying the javascript without the html.

Comment: You have to load jQuery first, then jQuery validation plugin.

Comment: There's no way you need all those fields to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: I would strongly SUGGEST you NOT use that old of a version of jQuery for too many reasons to count.

Comment: Perhaps add a link to the documentation for the specific validator (version 0.10.0 really?) you are using here.

Comment: Did you try closing with an } and comma  in `messages: { },`

Comment: You may use the "pattern" attribute, for example `<input type="text" name="fullname" pattern="[a-zA-Z\s]+" ... >`